# What can be put in 'Full HTML' node/fields?

Tags: nodes, theming

The obvious answer to this question is HTML code of course, but my deeper question is, is this an `HTML body` content-like HTML? I suppose I can't put `HTML header` content-like HTML? Correct? I mean I can't put `META tags` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You technically can use `<meta>` tags, since they will not be stripped out of the content that you place into a textfield that uses the default "full HTML" input filter. However, this content will be output in the `<body>` of the HTML document, which means using `<meta>` tags here will cause invalid HTML and most likely be ineffectual.

If you are looking for a way to customize the `<meta>` tags used on your Drupal site, there are many modules available to help with this. The [Meta Tags](http://drupal.org/project/metatag) module is the most popular, but that project's page also lists some other meta tag-related modules.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal themes are broken down into [regions](http://drupal.org/node/171224), where content and other blocks are displayed. Therefore, you can add any HTML that would be valid inside whatever container your content region is wrapped in (typically a `<div>`). So the `<header>` tag would work if you're supporting HTML5, but `<head>` won't work as you'd expect, because you're putting it in the `<body>` of your document.

If you want to edit markup outside of that region, or even modify regions, have a look at the [breakdown of core templates](http://drupal.org/node/190815).

If you're looking to edit `<meta>` tags specifically, have a look at the [Meta tags](http://drupal.org/project/metatag) module.

Answer (score 1):

When the full HTML is set as input format, what entered is not filtered in any way; this means that you could also enter tags that are not normally supported where you are adding them, such as `<meta>` tags that would appear inside the `<body>` tag, or miss a closing tag, such as in `<div><strong>This is wrong</div>`.

If you want to avoid both those problems, you could use the filtered input format, and add all the tags you are sure your users need, leaving out tags such as `<meta>`, which should not be added in the `<body>` tag.
It would also avoid there aren't tags left open, which would cause layout/formatting problems, when the users leave open tags. In fact, the code used to filter the entered HTML, in that case, is the following one.

```
  $allowed_tags = preg_split('/\s+|<|>/', $filter->settings['allowed_html'], -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
  $text = filter_xss($text, $allowed_tags);

  if ($filter->settings['filter_html_nofollow']) {
    $html_dom = filter_dom_load($text);
    $links = $html_dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
    foreach ($links as $link) {
      $link->setAttribute('rel', 'nofollow');
    }
    $text = filter_dom_serialize($html_dom);
  }
```